# How to prompt user to choose between browser or app when play youtube video in webview android

Tags: android, android-webview

I created a simple browser in android using Web-view. I have a Text-edit and a go button. When i got to YouTube i can play the video fine, but when I turn device sideways video stop and ask to play again, then it wont play anymore or any other videos. Is there a way to prompt user to choose between browser or YouTube app when click play in video?
Also is there a way to make android realize my app is a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser( shareIntent, title ));
```

Where shareIntent is the intent you want to launch (the intent to show the video).  It will create a chooser with all of the apps which can handle that intent.

TO make android realize you're a web browser, you need to set up an intent filter that says you can view the HTML mime type.

Comment: Thanks, i manage to to android recognize my app as a browser, but i cant figure out where or how in my main.java to set and format this intent for YouTube. Also how can i set up  geturl() to show the current url in the EditText bar so it can actually look like a url bar ?